# SingleThreadedSpinner error: json_prolog launch knowrob

Tags: ros, json-prolog, knowrob, spinning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am starting two threads using a predicate as query in json_prolog: one for subscribing to topics and other pops the callback to make assertions. There are separate spin() for both of them. It is similar to the one given in knowrob_perception_tutorial. When I start the json_prolog node, and start the thread by querying a predicate, I get "SingleThreadedSpinner: use MultiThreadedSpinner" error. The same code works perfectly with rosprolog load method. This is after I solved [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/196345/cannot-use-java-classes-to-execute-prolog-predicates/) error. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198837/singlethreadedspinner-error:-json_prolog-launch-knowrob/) by [olchandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20525/olchandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are using the catkinized KnowRob that uses rosjava, not rosjava_jni, right? There is no spinner in rosjava any more, see [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/overview.html). It may be that you have been confused by the old Java files in knowrob_perception_tutorial (that used the older rosjava_jni), which I had forgotten to remove. [This](https://github.com/knowrob/knowrob_tutorials/blob/indigo-devel/knowrob_perception_tutorial/knowrob_perception_tutorial/src/main/java/org/knowrob/tutorials/DummySubscriber.java) is the current approach to use.

If you use the older, rosbuild-based KnowRob that is based on rosjava_jni: This rosjava version wraps around roscpp, which would explain your error message. Spin() may only be called by [one thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/47505/calling-rosspin-from-a-new-thread/), i.e. you can remove the calls to 'spin()' in the other threads. However, I'd recommend to avoid rosjava_jni altogether since it's not actively maintained any more.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [olchandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20525/olchandra/) on 2014-12-04**:
Thank you Moritz. I have installed Knowrob in fuerte, so I am afraid I'll have to use rosjava_jni. Do you think I can have rosjava(catkinized) working in fuerte or, if there is another workaround? Currently it does not accept even a single spin() from my class and throws the above error.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-12-04**:
Have you tried to simply remove the spin()? As long as it's called in one thread, the messages should still be processed, so I expect everything to be fine. If there was no other spin(), you would not get this error message.

**Comment by [olchandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20525/olchandra/) on 2014-12-08**:
Hi. Yes. removing all the spin() and sub-shutdown() did the job. Thanks